# Cheaper method to expose AWS ECS via HTTPS than ELB/ALB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Building some personal projects and want to use AWS ECS to become more familiar with it, containerize my apps, and eventually set up CI/CD.

I understand a best practice to expose an ECS cluster for use publicly is to put an ALB or ELB in front of it and use that for HTTPS, and communicate via HTTP between ECS and ALB/ELB. But the load balancers are expensive and I would prefer not to spend $18/month just for a load balancer.

Is there a cheaper way I can set up HTTPS in front of my ECS container without taking on too much additional complexity? I don't plan on scaling beyond 1 container for the near future.

Thank you!

Comment: ALB is included in free tier. You are past a free tier usage?

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, unfortunately my free tier is long gone ;(

Comment: Are you using EC2-based containers? Then you can attach EIP to the instance. It won't be scalable nor fault-tolerant but for personal projects could be enough.

Comment: Alternatively if you are using Fargate then you can use public IP addresses directly. Unfortunately you can't use Route53 service discovery for the public addresses as that would allow you to scale the service to multiple tasks or have clients discover new tasks after deployment based on DNS.